Advice on using forstner bit with a corded drill
I am making a cosman workbench
I now have to attach the glued stretcher (57mm thick plywood) with bolts to the legs. I bought a 54mm forstner bit to bore a flat bottom hole (need 38mm depth) in the stretcher to hold the bolt end and nut.
shown at 2:34 in video
I am just not able to drive the forstner bit with my Bosch GSB 501 corded drill, the outside score line and center point seem to go in fine but the bulk is not getting removed. I am using low rpms and as I try to put more force my drill blocks out and stops.
This is my bit

I tried looking for solutions and came to know that this 2" bit might be too big for hand drilling, also it's a cheap one so not sure if the blades are not sharpened properly ( I did smell and observe light smoke in initial run but I don't see any discoloration on the bit).
Can anyone please suggest what can i do now?

I only have 1 drill, do I have to get a cordless drill which will have torque adjustments which might help
drive the forstner or get a entry-level drill press to finish this?

Should I get a different type of forstner bit (saw tooth etc?)

Buy a 20 or 25mm spade bit and work in sections to carve out the 54mm hole

Any other cost effective resolution for this.


Or should I drop the entire idea of flat bottom and just go through all the way with a hole saw - this may be a last option for me as I do want the flat bottom look.
Also I realize now that I made a mistake before gluing I should have used hole saw in 2  plys - this would have formed the flat bottom as I joined the 3rd piece.

If you’ve started the hole with the forstner, you could follow using a holesaw without the pilot bit, then finish with the forstner. Intuition says that even a cheap forstner will do better when the walls have been pre-cut.

FWIW, it’s true that while corded drills can be generally more powerful than the cordless ones, they are not all created equal. For example, my 18v cordless drill has way way more torque at low speeds than my corded drill (a green Bosch, a bit more basic than yours) because it has a gearbox. So even if it’s not needed here, you might want to upgrade your drill down the line if you plan to work on projects that require big holes (e.g. stick chairs).

@AloysiusDefenestrate even if I follow with a holesaw still the forstner has to work to remove the bulk, in my case the forstner is going well into the wall, it's the blade that's giving me problems with bulk removal, little bit pressure and my drill gets stuck and very little material gets removed.

@stanch so a 18v cordless can handle such a task with ease?

I don’t think it will handle a 54mm forstner bit (nor should it be used outside of a drill press). But it will make reasonably big holes with other bits! I’ve successfully used a 35mm auger with mine on a 10cm thick ash slab, while the corded drill refused to even start the hole. I would not go any larger though.

You've gotten good solutions in @stanch's excellent Answer so I won't add one of my own, but realise that a 54mm diameter is a honkin' big hole by any standards, even in plywood or softer solid wood species. That said this might have been possible with the right Forstner bit (or similar), however the bits capable of doing it could be prohibitively expensive at this size, so a workaround solution was probably the way to go right from the outset. [Edit: one suitable bit over here is £150 (just under $200) and it's not the most expensive option!]

I would agree that your bit is too big for a hand drill. However, based on the video, the hole can be any shape as long as it allows you to insert and tighten the nut, and it does not need to have a perfectly flat bottom. So you don’t need to make a big circular hole!
Instead, get a smaller forstner bit, 15 to 20 mm, and drill several adjacent holes as needed. Those work well with hand drills (at moderate to high, not super slow speeds). Pause and retract the bit often to clear the debris. The advantage of a forstner bit in this case is that you can slightly overlap the holes, while a spade bit might slip if you did that. That said, it would still work with a spade bit, which is also cheaper.
Finally, use a chisel to remove the walls between the holes, level the bottom and square up the overall shape. This is similar to how you would do an inlay (see e.g. this video). You can of course do the whole thing with a chisel alone, but it takes more time.

Thanks for the suggestion. I bought a 20mm forstner bit yesterday and it worked really well and went in smoothly, I'll go with a rectangular overall cut instead of a circle as suggested.

Great to hear it worked!
